# Can't add device to Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm not being able to add Provising Profiles to my app.

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxLRX.png)

So, from Edit or Add Provisioning Profile inside developer.apple.com I can't add device to the profile. I have no idea what the problem can be.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you haven't the `private key` in your `keychan`.
Before create a `provisioning profile`, you need to submit a certificate created from your keychan to Apple, and then download another certificate generate from Apple.

At this point you will have a `private key` in your `keychan`.

Probabilly you **created that provisioning profile from another computer**, and so in this mac **you don't have the private key**.
Due the fact that i see you not expert on this, i suggest you to start again the process to **create a new certificate and update the provisioning profile**.

If you are not expert in this, there are a lot of guide and video directly from apple in the [Apple Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).